# Sql Authenticated Connection String for AspNetDb

Tags: connection-string

Before I begin I would like to say I have already checked thoroughly at [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) and looked at all possible threads at this forum for an answer.

Right now my connection string is like this:

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Its working, but I can only access it in my App_Data folder
**I want to access this database from the SQL SSMS, therefore I have tried changing it like this:**

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
     Database=AspNetDb;InitialCatalog=ASPNETDB; User Id=kaneXtreme;Password=password123!;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

**I have also tried this**

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AspNetDb;
     Initial Catalog=ASPNETDB; User Id=kaneXtreme;Password=password123!" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Both of which I have tried changing is resulting in this **Configuration error** when I open up localhost:

> The entry `LocalSqlServer` has already been added.

Advice please.

Comment: I have checked for the possibility of another connection string in my other web.config file in my project as well as machine.config and web.config under the .NetFramework 4.0 Config folder. I could not find any there. What is weird is i looked into my .NetFramework 2.0 config folder and in both web.config and machine.config this ASPNETDB connection string is specified. Is this right? I am using version 4.0 of .NetFramework. Why is it using the connection string from the 2.0 folder? Some default aspnetdb.mdf setting? How can i override this ?

Answer (score 1):

If your using a username and password I think you need to change `Integrated Security=SSPI` to `Integrated Security=True`

eg.

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ASPNETDB;User id=kaneXtreme password=password123!;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to clear your connection strings before adding the first one.
By default, there is a "hidden" LocalSqlServer connection string in your machine.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear/>
<add name="LocalSqlServer" and-so-on-and-so-forth ...
```